# Display heading inline with dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, ruby-on-rails-4, inline

I am having way too much trouble with what should be a super easy task.

I want a heading *Status* displayed as the same line as my dropdown, but it is always on the next line. Im using Rails 4 and the bootstrap gem

```
<div class="status-area">

  <%= form_for project, {:class => "form-inline"} do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <h4>Status</h4>
      <%= f.select(:status, options_for_select(Status::STATUSES.collect { |s| [s.capitalize, s] }, project.status.to_s.downcase), {}, {:class => "form-control input-sm"}) %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit 'Update Project Status', class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm', style: 'padding: 2px 10px;' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Also some help with figuring out why the dropdown is the full width of the division would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you'll need to change h4 into a label tag (inline by default)

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <label>Status</label>
         <select class="form-control input-sm"></select>
    </div>
   <input class='btn btn-default btn-sm' style='padding: 2px 10px;'/>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bsgNQ/ - stretch the result window full width.

and secondly, it's said in the Bootstrap tutorial that inline form only applies to forms within viewports that are at least 768px wide. So it might be good to reconsinder using inline-form if your screen is narrower.